# dynamically get image and description php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display image and its description(on hover) dynamically in localhost

```
$c=mysql_connect("localhost","abc","xyz");
mysql_select_db("root");
q="select * from product";
$qc=mysql_query($q); 
while($ans=mysql_fetch_array($qc))
{
    print "<img id='display_img' src='products/$ans[8]'width=300 height=200>";
    print $ans[9] ;
}
```

but this shatters every think. I want to display image description on top of image.

i tried this

```
  <?php
                $c=mysql_connect("localhost","abc","xyz");
                mysql_select_db("root");
                $q="select * from product";
                $qc=mysql_query($q);
                $count=0;
                while($ans=mysql_fetch_array($qc))
                    {
                        if($count==0||$count==1||$count==2)
                        {

                            $title=$ans[1]." ".$ans[2];
                            print '<div class="img-wrap">';
                            print "<img id='display_img' src='products/$ans[8]'width=300 height=200 title='$title'>";
                            print '<div class="img-overlay">';
                            print '<h4>'.$title.'</h4>';
                            print '<p>'.$ans[9].'</p>';
                            print '</div>';
                            print '</div>';
                        }
                        $count++;
                        if($count==3)
                        {
                            print "<br />";
                            $count=0;
                        }
                    }   
        ?>

css code

.img-wrap
{
height:200px;
position:relative;
width:300px;
margin:10px;
}
.img-overlay
{
background-color:#000;
bottom:0;
color:#fff;
height:200px;
width:300px;
opacity:0;
position:absolute;
z-index:1000;
transition-duration:0.5s;
cursor:pointer;
}
.img-overlay h4, .img-overlay p{
padding:0 10px;
}
.img-wrap:hover .img-overlay{
opacity:0.75;
transition:opacity 0.5s;
}
b
{
    background-color:#aa490e;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:36px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    padding-left:65px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```

it gives me vertical output:

http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/4149/kn0b.png

but i want output like :

http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/8114/it5a.png

Comment: By "this shatters every think" do you mean "it's broken"? If so, **how is it broken?**

Comment: $ans[8] contain image and $ans[9] contain description of it

Comment: To display it on hover, you need to use ajax.. so your php will fetch content from database and ajax will render the fetched content on hover

Comment: Please clarify what doesn't work.  The question is very hard to understand at the moment.

Comment: an id has to be unique. every image will have the same id, don´t do that.

Comment: when i try to print desc with image it is : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/5/3cj9.png/                     and without desc it is : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/hhmn.png/ and i want that when i hover on image it shows desc

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting image and description next to it ?

---

As mentioned in comment, the output you are getting is correct as per code

so you need to change your code from

```
while($ans=mysql_fetch_array($qc)){
   print "<img id='display_img' src='products/$ans[8]'width=300 height=200>";
   print $ans[9] ;
}
```

to

```
while($ans=mysql_fetch_array($qc)){
{
    print "<img id='img_$ans[8]' src='products/$ans[8]' width=300 height=200 title='$ans[9]' >";
}
```

and if needed you can use jquery ui's tooltip for displaying description is much controlled manner

Comment: when i try to print desc with image it is : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/5/3cj9.png/                     and without desc it is : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/hhmn.png/ and i want that when i hover on image it shows desc

Comment: yes , this is the correct output as per your code

What you need to do is place the description as "title" attribute in the image and I would recommend using jquery ui tooltip to show the description in proper way

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the description in a div class/I'd and use jQuery to hide the text (or CSS would be better) the just jQuery hover effect to display the text withe the corresponding image etc